# Crystal Report Load Report Failed Error on Client Machine (VB.Net Win Forms)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Been breaking my head overnight with this. Couldn't get any help from earlier forums.

My app runs smoothly on other computers, it's been installed on five clients now with no problems. On this new machine, I keep getting the **"Load Report Failed"** when I open a report. It just leaves the CR Viewer blank afterwards.

**UPDATE:** I've checked the permissions, the app is able to make temporary files on the temp folder. But on my dev machine, it creates 2 files (the other file has curly brackets on it), on this particular client machine (where the error occurs), it only creates one.

I copy the bin folder content to client computers. The reports are set to **Embedded Resource** for **Build Action** and **Do not Copy** for **Copy to Output Directory**. This settings have run smoothly over the years with no problems on other client machines. I did not change anything in the report-retrieving code.

This is a sample code I've been using:

```
        Try
            Dim CR As New CRInventory
            CR.SetDataSource(DataTable)
            CR.SetParameterValue("GeneratedBy", ActiveStaffMember.Fullname)
            CR.SetParameterValue("BusinessDetails", BusinessName & ", " & BusinessAddress)
            CR.SetParameterValue("ReportDate", ReportDate)
            CRV.ReportSource = CR
        Catch ex As TypeInitializationException
            ShowApplicationRuntimeErrorNotebox("LoadReport TypeInitializationException", ex.InnerException.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ShowApplicationRuntimeErrorNotebox("LoadReport", ex.Message)
        End Try
```

So what's new with this computer? I don't know, it has the latest Windows update I guess?

Any help will do, please. I'm this close to throwing this new computer out of the window.

**UPDATE:** Used *ex.tostring* instead of *ex.Message* to somehow catch the error (thanks Seb) and this went out:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.EnsureLoadReport()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataTable dataTable)
   at Iceberg.FItemInventoryReportB.LoadReport() in D:\Documents\Iceberg\Iceberg VS2017\Iceberg\Forms\Items\Inventory\Inventory Transactions\FItemInventoryReportB.vb:line 38
```

**UPDATE:** Used **procmon.exe** to monitor the app's file system activity during report loading. All results are a **SUCCESS**. Unless I'm barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: can you show the full error message (with stack trace - `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message`)?

Comment: Here's the first line of the error:

`CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.`

And the last line:

`at Iceberg.FItemInventoryReportB.LoadReport() in D:\Documents\Iceberg\Iceberg VS2017\Iceberg\Forms\Items\Inventory\Inventory Transactions\FItemInventoryReportB.vb:line 38`

That's my dev machine's directory. It's odd because it's the first time this happened. I even used a perfectly working copy from one the clients.

Why the error now and why on this new client machine?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch do you need the whole error? I updated the post.

Comment: line 38 is this line `CR.SetDataSource(DataTable)` right?

Comment: Yes, I never touched that code. What I'm doing now is a new deployment. Basically I just copied the working exe and dlls etc. and pasted it on the new client pc along with the prerequisite apps. This is the only client pc where this error occurs.

Comment: You installed the Crystal Reports runtime on the computer? All runtimes and developer editions depending on version here: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Comment: @SebastianBrosch thanks! I uninstalled the current CR runtine and installed the SP26 one. It works now! THANKS!